# Making a web page cache even if the parameters change

Tags: php, http, caching, header

Is there a way to get a browser to cache a web page even if the parameters change?

I have a web assembly app that takes parameters.  If the parameters change, the browser forces a download.  Is there any way I can set headers so that the parameters aren't a factor in caching?

i.e. if I do

```
http://www.example.com?param=1234
```

and

```
http//:www.example.com?param=4321
```

...the browser thinks it's a whole new site and downloads the whole 26mb web assembly binary again.

Anything I can do?

Comment: It `is` a different GET call, then. But where is the problem? Nobody would add parameters by himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Cache-Control header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control):

```php
<?php

header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800, immutable");
```

Comment: Chtiadrien, is there some way to make it so that if I replace the files with newer ones the server, it'll re-download?  I tried including Last-Modified but including that just makes it invalidate the cache every time.

Comment: You can use the "must-revalidate" header. You can check the Caching documentation to learn more on the subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching. Also check the Cache-Control documentation for usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control. NB: if you serve a file via a PHP script, you indeed use the last modification date of the file to response accordingly. You will have to play with Headers, but also HTTP Response Code.

Comment: If you don't mind... I'm doing this: header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800, immutable, must-revalidate");  ...and it's forcing a re-download of the WASM assets each time.  If I leave off must-revalidate, it works correctly, but then doesn't re-download even if I update things server side.  Any suggestions or anything I'm obviously doing wrong there?

Comment: This simply sends an "ordinary" Cache-Control header, how does this make the _browser_ caching independent of changing URL parameters?! (What this looks like is... the "26mb web assembly" is actually an entirely separate HTTP request - to a static PHP resource - and all you're doing here is ensuring the "26mb web assembly" is cached, not strictly the initially requested page with the changing URL parameter?)